# JPQL Parser failed to compile Named query which has JOIN FETCH in Nested queries

Tags: jpa-2.0

I am trying to execute the below Named query, but it fails to parse by JPQLParser. The query get parsed If i try to remove the below two bold lines containing JOIN FETCH.
I am using was 8 shipped JPA 2.X

Both the Business Object "applicationItem" and "application" which are JOIN FETCH are marked LAZY FETCH inside business class "AdmissionItem" and "ApplicationItem"

The below query is running absolutely fine in JPA 1.X but fails in JPA 2.X

### Named Query

```
"SELECT DISTINCT request FROM Request request  
            WHERE request.genId IN 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT applicationItem.request.genId 
                FROM ApplicationItem applicationItem
                WHERE applicationItem.genId IN 
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT admissionItem.applicationItem.genId 
                    FROM AdmissionItem admissionItem 
                    **JOIN FETCH admissionItem.applicationItem 
                    JOIN FETCH admissionItem.applicationItem.application**  
                    WHERE admissionItem.genId IN 
                    (
                        // more query


                    ) 
                 AND admissionItem.applicationItem.application.name='SMA'
                 )
 )"
```

### ERROR MESSAGE

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "request . genId IN ( SELECT DISTINCT applicationItem . request . genId FROM ApplicationItem applicationItem WHERE applicationItem . genId IN ( SELECT DISTINCT admissionItem . applicationItem . genId FROM AdmissionItem admissionItem JOIN FETCH" at character 31, but expected: ["(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", "<", "<=", "<>", "=", ">", ">=", "?", "ABS", "ALL", "AND", "ANY", "AS", "ASC", "AVG", "BETWEEN", "BOTH", "BY", "CONCAT", "COUNT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "DELETE", "DESC", "DISTINCT", "EMPTY", "ESCAPE", "EXISTS", "FETCH", "FROM", "GROUP", "HAVING", "IN", "INNER", "IS", "JOIN", "LEADING", "LEFT", "LENGTH", "LIKE", "LOCATE", "LOWER", "MAX", "MEMBER", "MIN", "MOD", "NEW", "NOT", "NULL", "OBJECT", "OF", "OR", "ORDER", "OUTER", "SELECT", "SET", "SIZE", "SOME", "SQRT", "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "TRAILING", "TRIM", "TYPE", "UPDATE", "UPPER", "WHERE", , , , , , , , , ]." while parsing JPQL

at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:51)

Comment: On the other hand, what's the point in fetching associations in a query which selects a single field? Why not remove the fetch, which is completely useless?

Comment: removing fetch still throws the same exception.

Comment: The message must have changed. Post your new query and the new error message, and change the title of the question,since it doesn't have anything to be with fetch, as it seems.

Comment: i removed the FETCH and used an alias name now it works fine                   JOIN admissionItem.applicationItem appItem
JOIN admissionItem.applicationItem.application app
but still not sure why the above changes make the query run in JPA 2.X